# Image is not covering whole area inside flex items

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have a following scss. Which put a box in the center.

```
:host {
  .auth-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 82vh;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .left-container {
    /* This will be twice as */
    /* big as the small item. */
    flex: 2 0 0;

    .background-container {
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-image: url("../../../../assets/background/signin.jpg");

    }
  }

  .right-container {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .auth-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

2 things not happening

1. I want to have a background image in the left container but the image is not covering the whole left container and its looking like following.
2. The login box is not centered. After addeding align-items: center its not centered to the right container.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the HTML, please?

Comment: Without any HTML it is hard to help you. What I can already tell is this. If you are trying to center the `.right-container` in relation to the `.left-container` than you need to set align-items on the parent container of the two, not on the `.right-container` or the `.left-container`.